# event.preventDefault() not being honored for a jquery.trigger("click")

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

There are checkboxes within a `form` on my page:

```
<form id="oneform" action="blah..">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="chkbox1"/>Checkbox1
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="chkbox2"/>Checkbox2
...
```

**NOTE**: upon checking/unchecking ***any*** checkbox this form is submitted. Here is jQuery code:

```
$("input[name='checkboxes']").bind("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    ....

    $("#oneform").submit();
});
```

The role of e.preventDefault() in above function is : if the checkbox was checked and the box is clicked, prevent default will ensure that it remains in checked condition for the browser to record checkbox state before form submission. So after form submission the checkbox will be unchecked as expected and on "Back button" I will see the checkbox checked again. This works for me as expected

Then I have a div on that form  which shows list of elements displaying name of checkboxes checked.

```
<div>
  <% This is a JSTL code: for each element  %>
      <a class="close-tag" href="#" value="<% JSTL put the checkbox id %>"><span><% jSTL put checkbox name</span> X</a>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

If you clicked on 'X' there is a jQuery Handler as shown below:

```
$(".close-tag").bind('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault() // again for same reasons as mentioned above

// get the name of checkbox id from event target
.....
 var selector = ... // checkbox id 

// fake the checkbox clicking event
$("#"+selector).trigger("click");
// doing the above goes to the above jquery snippet as you would expect.

// the checkbox also remains checked as expected due to e.preventDefault()
// However on server side it should send the checkbox as "unchecked" instead it sends as  checked
```

});

Did I miss to add anything? It does not work on FF, Chrome
Thanks for any pointers!

**Update**
By replacing `$(selector).trigger()` with vanilla JS alternative: `document.getElementById(selector).click()` ...I was able to solve this.
Works as expected on FF, IE8/9, safari, chrome, opera yay!

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Actually, I missed something really obvious. When you call `trigger()` you need to specify the event you want to trigger, so it needs to be `trigger('click')`.

---

If I'm reading it correctly, you're saying it still showed as checked, but you want it to report to the server as being unchecked.

That's not quite possible. An element doesn't have two states like that, just one.

What you could do though is change the check box to unchecked, submit the form, then mark it as checked again.

Comment: thanks for responding! ...when I check a checkbox by clicking on it this is the chain of events I see: `checked_checkbox --> click --> checkbox_still_checked --> form submit ---> page reload --> checkbox_now unchecked`.   Now, when I fake click action via jquery.trigger() as I described above the flow is: `checked_checkbox --> fake click with trigger --> checkbox_still)_checked --> form submitted --> page reload --> checkbox_still_checked`  (expected checkbox_unchecked)

Comment: I believe something is going wrong when jquery.trigger() is faking click...probably event.preventDefault() is not being honored as it should....I put some debug points in Firebug...and I couldn't see a difference

Comment: I made a small update to my post. Noticed you weren't passing the event in to the trigger, which may be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out...in the question I forgot ..but in my code...it was there....thanks again!